# Dropdown selection populates div with hidden buttons that then populate another div with hidden content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, hidden, dropdown

I am trying to make a somewhat complicated form... and perhaps am making it more complicated than it needs to be!

The title says it all:

1. Select dropdown option
2. Based on dropdown selection, the designated div #info is populated with a hidden set of buttons (and changes button set based on which option is selected).
3. Those buttons can then be clicked to display hidden content in the additional designated div #info2 (which also changes content based on the button clicked).

In my fiddle, I tried to show what I am attempting to do, only I used buttons in place of the dropdown.

I hope this makes sense!

Edit: I want to be able to click/navigate freely between all buttons and dropdowns, in that when a particular choice is clicked, any content related to the previous choice will be removed from the div which will then be populated by the current div choice content.

---

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.buttons button').click(function (){
        $('#info').empty();
        $('#info').html($("#" + $(this).data('link')).html());
    });

 });

<body>
        <div class="want-this-to-be-dropdown">
            <ul id="button-column" style="list-style: none;">
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button1" data-link="option1">Button 1</button></li>
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button2" data-link="option2">Button 2</button></li>
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button3" data-link="option3">Button 3</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="info-div">
            <div id="info">

            </div>
        </div>
<div id="hiddenDivs" style="display:none;">
    <div class="info" id="option1">
      <div class="button-panel">
            <ul id="button-column" style="list-style: none;">
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button1" data-link="option4">Option 4</button></li>
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button2" data-link="option5">Option 5</button></li>
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button3" data-link="option6">Option 6</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="info-div">
            <div id="info2">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info" id="option2">
      <div class="button-panel">
            <ul id="button-column" style="list-style: none;">
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button1" data-link="option7">Option 7</button></li>
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button2" data-link="option8">Option 8</button></li>
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button3" data-link="option9">Option 9</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="info-div">
            <div id="info2">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info" id="option3"><div class="button-panel">
            <ul id="button-column" style="list-style: none;">
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button1" data-link="option10">Option 10</button></li>
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button2" data-link="option11">Option 11</button></li>
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button3" data-link="option12">Option 12</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="info-div">
            <div id="info2">

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>


        <div class="info" id="option3"><div class="button-panel">
            <ul id="button-column" style="list-style: none;">
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button1" data-link="option10">Fee</button></li>
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button2" data-link="option11">Fi</button></li>
                <li class="buttons"><button id="button3" data-link="option12">Foo</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="info-div">
            <div id="info2">

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

[Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lcunning/Ln205dwz/)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so here it goes...

Let's say you have a select field:

```js
function func() {
  var val = document.getElementById("select").value;
  
  if(val == "bla") {
    document.getElementById("bla").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  
  if(val == "blo") {
    document.getElementById("blo").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="select" onchange="func()">
  <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">Label 1</option>
  <option value="bla">bla</option>
  <option value="blo">blo</option>
</select>


<div id="bla" style="visibility:hidden; width:30px; height:20px; background-color:#f00"></div>

<div id="blo" style="visibility:hidden; width:30px; height:20px; background-color:#ff0"></div>
```

Do you get the idea?

I'm sorry, I just saw that you used jQuery........... You would have smth like a class with visibility:hidden and toggle it with jQuery... The equivalent event  would be change(). Well, this still should ring a bell. If you need further help (like with jQuery) don't hesitate to ask.

:-)

Comment: I think I see what you are saying here, but it's not quite the answer I am looking for. In your code example, I clicked on one dropdown selection and then the other, but the previous content did not disappear. I get how dropdowns work, but I don't know how to connect them with hidden content to populate a div. If you look at my fiddle, you'll (hopefully) see what I am trying to do.

Comment: I did look at your fiddle. Thats why i mentioned jQuery's toggle. Well give me a second, I will code you something working really quick.

Answer (score 1):

So here is the other approach...

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.buttons button').click(function (){
        $('#info').empty();
        $('#info').html($("#" + $(this).data('link')).html());
    });
});

function func() {
    $(".info").each(function() {
        $(this).css("display", "none");
    });
    
    var val = $("#select").val();
    
    if(val == "bla") {
        $("#option1").css("display", "block"); 
    }
 
    if(val == "blo") {
        $("#option2").css("display", "block"); 
    }
}
```

```css
#button-column {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
button {
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 15px; 
}

#info {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding-top: 37.5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.info {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="want-this-to-be-dropdown">
    <ul id="button-column" style="list-style: none;">
        <select id="select" onchange="func()">
            <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">Label 1</option>
            <option value="bla">bla</option>
            <option value="blo">blo</option>
        </select>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="info-div">
    <div id="info">
        <div class="info" id="option1">
            <div class="button-panel">
                <ul id="button-column" style="list-style: none;">
                    <li class="buttons"><button id="button1" data-link="option4">Option 1</button></li>
                    <li class="buttons"><button id="button2" data-link="option5">Option 2</button></li>
                    <li class="buttons"><button id="button3" data-link="option6">Option 3</button></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="info-div">
                <div id="info1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info" id="option2">
            <div class="button-panel">
                <ul id="button-column" style="list-style: none;">
                    <li class="buttons"><button id="button1" data-link="option4">Option 4</button></li>
                    <li class="buttons"><button id="button2" data-link="option5">Option 5</button></li>
                    <li class="buttons"><button id="button3" data-link="option6">Option 6</button></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="info-div">
                <div id="info2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code itself shouldn't be too hard to understand. If you have trouble though, I can break it down for you :-)

Comment: Thanks for trying again -- still not quite what I am looking for. Two primary problems here: I can move between the two dropdown divs but when I click one of the buttons that populate the div, I am unable to move back to the other dropdown. Second problem is that there is no additional div (see #info2 in my example) being populated with content when you click one of the buttons. I am going for the ability to navigate freely between dropdown options, buttons. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think I figured it out. Thanks so much for your suggestions!

Comment: Oh okay, I only intended on showing in which direction this could go. But I'm happy you managed nevertheless!